# Retrieve from html body

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

From this HTML body of a mail ,How can I retrieve only the body(Hi...Thank You) to a text box

```
   <html><body><div style="color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, Sans-Serif;font-size:14px"><div>Hi...ThankYou</div></div></body></html>
```

Thank You

Comment: In a generic case, it is a very hard task. See for example https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at HTML parsing libraries like [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or [`CsQuery`](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)

Here is how it's done in CsQuery (the selector syntax is compatible with jquery):

```
    Dim html = "<html><body><div style=""color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, Sans-Serif;font-size:14px""><div>Hi...ThankYou</div></div></body></html>"
    Dim cs = CsQuery.CQ.Create(html)
    Dim txt = cs("body>div>div").Text()

    textBox.Text = txt
```

you can obtain CsQuery through Nuget using `PM> Install-Package CsQuery -Version 1.3.4` command

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div");
```